# context:property-placeholder how to reference the property bean

Tags: spring, properties, property-placeholder

We have this existing property loader configuration in our spring context

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <util:list>
            <value>hedging-service.properties</value>
        </util:list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!--Hedging properties bean that can be injected into other beans-->
<util:properties id="hedgingProperties" location="classpath:hedging-service.properties"/>
```

and there is a bean which references the `hedgingProperties` bean

```
<bean id="mailProcessor"
    class="a.b.c.MailProcessor">
    <property name="properties" ref="hedgingProperties"/>
    ...
</bean>
```

I'm refactoring the context to load from multiple property files and also avoid the duplicate definition of the properties. My first attempt is to use this bean in place of the two above

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:hedging-service-core.properties,classpath:hedging-service.properties,classpath:icon.properties"/>
```

but how can I retain the alias or reference to the `hedgingProperties` bean when I use the `context:property-placeholder`?

Comment: Do you mean this `properties-ref="hedgingProperties"`? An attribute of `<context:property-placeholder>`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a mixture `context:property-placeholder` and `util:properties`

```
<util:properties id="hedgingProperties" location="classpath:hedging-service.properties"/>
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="hedgingProperties" />

<bean id="mailProcessor" class="a.b.c.MailProcessor">
    <property name="properties" ref="hedgingProperties"/>
    ...
</bean>
```

Comment: Yes and No. The util:properties doesn't support loading multiple files via the location value

Comment: Well, use `PropertiesFactoryBean` instead with its `locations` property

Comment: @ArtemBilan I agree. For multiple properties files looks like reasonable solution